# Change Picture I to Picture II

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

**Picture 1**

[image: Picture 1]

**Picture 2**

[image: Picture 2]

> Can you alter just 5 characters to make Picture 1 exactly as Picture
>   2?

Comment: This puzzle would have been much better if there sentences were nearly alike. Because they are so distant you can instantly rule out anything in the actual picture.

Comment: This seems to be just asking for a suggested edit with the solution... Too bad I'm past the suggesting phase.

Comment: @Lolgast I am new to puzzling. Will take some time to develop better and harder puzzles.

Comment: No offense/critique at your question was intended! What I was trying to say, is that it is tempting to "answer" by editing 5 characters in the body, thus changing picture 1 to picture 2... :P Or did you mean to notify @GeorgeReith ?

Comment: Incidentally, you can change picture 1 to picture 2 just by incrementing one character...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Maybe..

> Change from [https://i.stack.imgur.com/**kV7fT**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV7fT.jpg)
>  to [https://i.stack.imgur.com/**U36de**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U36de.jpg)

LOL

Comment: If this is not the answer I'm going to be annoyed.

Comment: Yup, my thoughts exactly. Have a +1.

Answer (score 38):

> Looking at the URLs for both pictures, I would alter the letters kV7fT in the first picture's URL to U36de to give the second picture's URL.

Comment: Beaten by 12 seconds to it. That sucks.